# Si usa «ziff!» quando si starnutisce?

Tags: word-meaning

Il dizionario [dice](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=zif) che, quando qualcuno taglia una corda con un coltello, si può dire «ziff!». In questo brano da Pirandello («Il fu Mattia Pascal») c'è uno che, evidentemente, starnutisce:

> Non giovavano a nulla le vendette che di questi suoi tradimenti noi ci prendevamo. Eppure ricordo che non eran da burla. Una sera, per esempio, io e Berto, sapendo che egli soleva dormire, seduto su la cassapanca, nella saletta d’ingresso, in attesa della cena, saltammo furtivamente dal letto, in cui ci avevano messo per castigo prima dell’orasolita, riuscimmo a scovare una canna di stagno, da serviziale, lunga due palmi, la riempimmo d’acqua saponata nella vaschetta del bucato; e, così armati, andammo cautamente a lui, gli accostammo la canna alle nari — e zifff! — Lo vedemmo balzare
>   fin sotto al soffitto.

A che evento veramente riferisce quel «ziff»? Qual è l'origine di quel suono in questa situazione? Credo che sia l'atto di starnutire, ma mi mette in dubbi quel riferimento nel dizionario…

Comment: Personalmente prenderei con molta cautela quel sito che hai consultato: lo ha fatto un tale qualsiasi, come me o te, non una redazione di linguisti, come il Treccani, il De Mauro, lo Zingarelli, lo Hoepli... Comunque in questo caso sembra aver ragione sul colpo secco di un oggetto tagliente e simili (vedi [qui](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/ziff) e relativo rimando, nonché altri dizionari sotto la voce “ziffe”). [segue]

Comment: [segue] Nel testo di Pirandello, però, io personalmente non ci vedo né un colpo di oggetto da taglio né uno starnuto, ma un sobbalzo, un gesto con cui il personaggio a cui fanno lo scherzo si muove di scatto per il contatto inatteso con l'acqua.

Comment: @DaG Cioè, la parola in questo brano non dovrebbe riferire a nessun suono fatto, ma solo alla rapidità del suo balzare (paragonata al modo in cui si può sentire talvolta suoni inattesi, bruschi)?

Comment: Nella mia esperienza, lo starnuto è rappresentato con "ecciù!"

Comment: Sì, la mia impressione intuitiva è questa, @Evgeniy, ma sono aperto a correzioni.

Comment: Grazie a tutti. Mi risulta chiara ora la «logica del testo». Certo, ci sono sempre variabilità nel capire il senso esatto dell'espressioni, ma il testo è artistico, allora le variabilità nel caso presente ora credo non siano importanti… Anche se la mia domanda sì le ha riferite.

Comment: Secondo il [dizionario Hoepli](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/E/ecci.php) ed anche il De Mauro si usa anche "eccì" o "etcì" per imitare il suono dello starnuto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo starnuto sarebbe "etciù" o simili, ed è un'onomatopea molto radicata, quindi non credo che ne avrebbe usata un'altra. "Ziff" in quel contesto mi fa pensare all'acqua che schizza fuori dalla canna.

Comment: Quando scrivi “ectciù” intendi “etciù”, o esiste anche questa versione? E sai per caso se questa onomatopea si usasse così già ai tempi di Pirandello? Lo Zingarelli, alla voce “eccì” (che tratta insieme alle varianti ecciù, etcì, etciù, atciù), mette come anno di prima occorrenza il 1956.

Comment: Scusami, errore di ortografia, non esiste.. sarebbe etciù o ecciù, ora edito